# Is there a JavaScript Method/ Function to loop Objects via Keys into a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, chart.js

Hy , this is my API

```
 // --- API
        // Replace ./data.json with your JSON feed
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/cars/')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                // Work with JSON data here
                //-- go to array named "results"
                obj1 = data.results 
                console.dir(obj1) 

<...>
```

this is my API Output. Some Array with Objects and Random Data.

> [{"id":3,"name":"Audi","price":11},{"id":2,"name":"Mercedes","price":22},{"id":1,"name":"BMW","price":99},{"id":4,"name":"Trabant","price":113}]

I would like to loop the Objects by their key into different arrays in JavaScript. So that Chart.js can handle it as labels, for instance.

**Example**

> ["Audi", "Mercedes", "BMW", "Trabant"]

So i tried these three different Methods to do the job

```
Object.keys
Object.values
Object.entries
```

An i also tried a loop

```
                // --- LOOP
                var arr = obj1
                for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    console.dir(arr[i]);
                }
                console.dir(arr)
```

But i only get rid of the **[ ]** with the loop
and in the end its a too messy. So i ask myself is there something like

```
{% for some_value in Object.name %}
{{ some_value ]}
{% endfor %}
```

like in Django? A simple Loop through Objects by their key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try (we use standard [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

```js
let d = [{"id":3,"name":"Audi","price":11},{"id":2,"name":"Mercedes","price":22},{"id":1,"name":"BMW","price":99},{"id":4,"name":"Trabant","price":113}];

let r= d.map(x=>x.name);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `map`.

```
let result = arr.map(({name}) => name);
```

The array `result` will have the name of the brands.

*Example*

```js
let arr = [{"id":3,"name":"Audi","price":11},{"id":2,"name":"Mercedes","price":22},{"id":1,"name":"BMW","price":99},{"id":4,"name":"Trabant","price":113}];

let result = arr.map(({name}) => name);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: I add +1 to your answer some time ago - nice construction with {name} - I don't know it

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski that's called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).